# @JsonIgnoreProperties doesn't allow to set values via @RequestBody?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to allow to serialize my object excluding some fields. So say I have a class:

```
class UserInfo {
        String userName;
        String password;

        //getters & setters
    }
```

And I need to serialize it for some purpose but excluding password field. So I added:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"password"}) //or
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"amountDelta"}, allowGetters = true, allowSetters = true)
```

Then, I'm trying to wrap an instance of my class via `@RequestBody`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = POST, produces = "application/json")
    public String testBodyWrapping(@RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {    

        return userInfo.getPassword();
    }
```

The password is always `null`! (I tested this removing `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation, and it worked) But creating an instance of a class "by-hand" work as expected and `password` field doesn't come out. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone use this endpoint, it send json text. Your method deserializing it to UserInfo class object. During this process deserializer trying to set each field of UserInfo class. First it try to set 'userName' field and it's ok, after that it find 'password' field as ignorable and doesn't set in. Thats all.

Comment: So it means that @RequestBody translates my request via serialization? Can I achieve what I want in some other way?

Comment: Tell me pls what you want to do with this object? You got full object and what next? Where you need to ignore password field?

Comment: I have an object that should be send as `RabbitMQ` message. There're some fields that should be passed (amount, id, refName etc.) But request also requires password and signature params that shouldn't be sent to `RabbitMQ` and also I can't change request format since it's already used by a lot of users.

Comment: Maybe you should to use UserInfoDTO object without some fields?

Comment: That's what came in my mind but I thought it's not a good practice... But it turned out to be a pattern! So it seems to be helpful, I'll look at it. Thanks (greets from Ukraine :D)